# Python [panda/lambda] - group and aggregate on DF by specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, aggregate, grouping

In DF have multiple fields:

```
parent_path, child, level, flag, logic
```

I want to group the DF by `parent_path`, and collect all children under same parent.

I got to this:

```
curr_level.groupby('parnet_path').agg(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index()
```

It is working and it does collect all children having same parent in a list,
but it also listing/aggregating all other columns in the dataframe.

How can I group by specific group and AGG by specific columns ?

Comment: I dont get what exactly your looking for but I think this line of code gives all the childs listed /parent_path . you just need to specify the column curr_level.groupby('parnet_path').agg(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index() ['child']

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('parnet_path')[["column1","column2"]].agg(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index()
```

column1 and column 2 are some specific columns.

Your case:

```
  df.groupby('parnet_path')["child"].agg(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks @Ena , but by specifying the coulms as you mention :
```
 df.groupby('parnet_path')["child"].agg(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index() 
``` 
this actually returing 2 columns - the parent with all the Childs , but what about all the other columns in DF?
I'